# Listing directory takes forever on a folder that used to have millions of files

Tags: filesystems, ext4, slowdown

The filesystem is ext4, the machine hasn't been rebooted in years and we don't want to do that now either.

We used to have a folder with millions of small (2-3kb of size) files. This almost broke the system so we fixed the code that was generating so many files and wrote a crontask that erased all the files within the directory (because `rm` wasn't working)

At first everything went smooth, you type `ls` and you got full list of the 4-5 remaining files.

On the next day however when I typed `ls` the system took forever to execute the command (it took minutes) and the system load went over **20** which scared me a lot.

It's basically like this for months now. The first time of the day when I do `ls` the system borderline slows to a crawl and eventually returns a list of ... 5 files and no subfolders.

I believe it's some ext4 cache, I've tried running various commands to no avail.

Is there anything else I could do to force ext4 to erase the cache.

The system is running in RAID 1 mode. Running `cat /proc/mdstat` shows that both drives are fully functional and synchronized. `smartctl` says the drive is in good health as well. hdparm returns the following

```
hdparm -tT /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1:
Timing cached reads:   19238 MB in  2.00 seconds = 9629.50 MB/sec
Timing buffered disk reads: 316 MB in  3.01 seconds = 104.92 MB/sec
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known problem with file systems in the Ext family; see [Why directory with large amounts of entries does not shrink in size after entries are removed?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/495176/86440) for details.

The only way to fix this is to re-create the directory. First, rename the existing directory (this will avoid problems with processes attempting to open files there):

```
mv brokendir repairdir/
```

Then, create a new directory (not using the old name, yet):

```
mkdir newdir
```

Move all the contents of the broken directory to the new directory:

```
mv repairdir/* newdir/
mv repairdir/.[!.]* newdir/
mv repairdir/..?* newdir/
```

(as three separate commands so that you know exactly what’s going on if one of them fails, *e.g.* if there are no hidden files to move).

You may want to ensure the new directory’s metadata is identical to the original’s, in particular its ownership and permissions; if you’re using GNU coreutils, this can be done (once `repairdir` is empty) with

```
cp -aT repairdir newdir
```

Finally, move everything back into place, and delete the old directory:

```
mv newdir brokendir/
rmdir repairdir
```