# Size discrepancy between "ls" and "du" calls

Tags: centos, directory, size

We are constantly low on space and look for files are installed programs in `/tmp` on out server. I notice the following for tmp but can't find a large file in `/tmp`.

```
drwxrwxrwt.  27 root   root            170131456 Jun 25 06:06 tmp
```

When I run

```
sudo du .
```

the total is `201184`, where is the discrepancy in size coming from?

Comment: Relating https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/252238/117549 (duplicate?)

Comment: I'm not clear what "discrepancy" you refer to. The output from `du` is (by default) the number of 1024-byte blocks. So that shows around 196MiB used by `/tmp` and all its component directories and files. The size reported by `ls` is just the size of the `/tmp` directory (namelist), and is 162MiB, so you have around 33MiB of files beneath that. A `df` report would tell more. The bottom line is that at one time, `/tmp` contained two or three million files at once (depending on the file system it belongs to).